# Hierarchical data in StringTemplate

Tags: stringtemplate

I am trying to create a hierarchical document using StringTemplate.

For example, a list of directories:

```
\alpha 
   \file1
   \file2
\beta
   \file3
\gamma
   \file4
   \file5
   \file6
```

Is this even possible with StringTemplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example would be:

*list.st*

```
$it.title$
    $it.children:list()$
```

*page.st*

```
$rootNode.children:list()$
```

For more information, you can read [An introduction to StringTemplate](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aberrant/archive/2010/05/25/using-stringtemplate-part-1-introduction-stringtemplate) (as well as [Collections and Template Groups](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aberrant/archive/2010/06/02/stringtemplate-part-2-collections-and-template-groups) and [Complex Data Types and Renderers](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aberrant/archive/2010/06/07/stringtemplate-part-3-complex-data-types-and-renderers) in this trilogy). And don't forget [official StringTemplate documentation](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/StringTemplate+Documentation).